# What CSS is neccessary to create inner panel on 100% width div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a semi-transparent background to lessen the interaction of the text with a textured background by using a semi-transparent div.  I can't seem to figure out how to write the CSS to achieve this effect when the parent div's dimentions are defined by a pixel value height and 100% width.

Apparently I can't use margin to "shrink" the div when the height and width are defined as 100%.  This is only a small section of the webpage so I'd like to avoid changing the entire layout to achieve this one effect.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="innerPanel"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#0183e5;
}
#innerPanel {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:15px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/qpYFV/1/

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is add `padding` to your parent container.

Here is the changed `CSS`:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#0183e5;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/qpYFV/2/)

I suggest using `box-sizing: border-box;` or `calc(100% - 20px)` to not worry about figuring out what sizes to set.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/qpYFV/4/) - `box-sizing: border-box;`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/qpYFV/7/) - `calc(100% - 20px)`

---

- [Box-sizing browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
- [Calc browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: As a side note you can also add `box-sizing:border-box;` to the container to have the padding included in the height.

Comment: ... As you just added to the answer ;-)

Comment: :p I'm a big fan of `box-sizing`.

Comment: Please note the compatibility of `box-sizing`. This may or may not be an issue for your specific project. http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: Of course browser support is always something to consider and `calc` actually has IE9 + support which is amazing.

Comment: Android browser, however, does not.  Neither does Opera mini.  Box-sizing has by far better support than calc().

Answer (score 3):

I suggest applying padding to your container, rather than margin on your inner panel.

Also, remove the width from your container and adjust the height to account for the padding.

```
#container {
    height:220px; /* 250-(15x2) */
    background-color:#0183e5;
    padding:15px;
}
#innerPanel {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qpYFV/5/